# findall in Visual Prolog 5.2

Tags: prolog

I have the following lines in the program:

```
findFlight(DepartureP,ArrivalP,FinalResult) :-
    findall([Flight,DepartureP,ArrivalP,DepartureTime,ArrivalTime],
            flight(Flight,DepartureP,ArrivalP,DepartureTime,ArrivalTime),
            Result),
    bubblesort(Result, FinalResult).
```

but my compiler gives the following warning:

```
E;Test_Goal, pos: 969, 410 Variable expected
```

and the cursor is here when I click on the warning:

findall(**|**[

what is the problem? this program on swi prolog worked fine, but the visual prolog environment issues a warning..

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Visual Prolog, but it looks like it needs a variable at the start of its findall, e.g.

```
findFlight(DepartureP,ArrivalP,FinalResult) :-
    findall(F,
            (flight(Flight,DepartureP,ArrivalP,DepartureTime,ArrivalTime),
             F = [Flight,DepartureP,ArrivalP,DepartureTime,ArrivalTime]),
            Result),
    bubblesort(Result, FinalResult).
```

Comment: it works on swi, but not on visual prolog, unfortunately. The compiler outputs that ',' or ')' expected.I also tried to pull the variable F outside of findall, but the compiler also swears this way. Visual Prolog supports the find all predicate, but apparently only for one variable, not an array of variables. Are there any other ways to get the records I need? I have to get a list of lists to sort it then.